# Group one Column CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get Resource and the assosiate skills to I want to ask if there are away to Group the skill in one Column to look like CSV
Like this
[image]

ID Skills
1, reading,Writing
2,Programing, reading

```
SELECT     Resources.Id, Skills.Description
FROM         Resources INNER JOIN
                      Skills_Resources ON Resources.Id = Skills_Resources.ResourceID INNER JOIN
                      Skills ON Skills_Resources.skillID = Skills.Id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to concatenate the multiple rows together you will need to use `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT distinct r.Id, 
    STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + cast(s.description as varchar(50))
          FROM Skills s
          INNER JOIN Skills_Resources sr
            ON sr.skillID = s.Id
          where r.Id = sr.ResourceID 
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS skills
FROM Resources r;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16b9e/9).

You could also use `CROSS APPLY` with `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select distinct r.Id,  
  left(s.skill, len(s.skill)-1) skills
from Resources r
cross apply
(
  select s.description + ', '
  FROM Skills s
  INNER JOIN Skills_Resources sr
    ON sr.skillID = s.Id
  where r.Id = sr.ResourceID 
  FOR XML PATH('')
) s (skill);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16b9e/10)